# How can I delete the right column in Komodo Edit 8?

Tags: komodoedit, code-editor

[Image Link](https://imgur.com/wi92uUq)

You see, I want to delete the column in which my cursor is present, but it's nowhere mentioned in the documentation how to do it.

I am using Komodo Edit 8. I even don’t know what it's called -right-column, right-column, markup, etc. This extra space is consuming too much room on my monitor.

Comment: The image link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komodo developer here. I'm assuming you are talking about the minimap. You can get rid of this either for the current file alone via menu *View* → *View Minimap* or globally via menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Scrolling* → *Use the Minimap Scrollbar*.

Documentation on the minimap can be found here: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/editor.html#Minimap.

Comment: thanks a lot, for both the best FREE IDE and for helping out !!